# jQuery .after function for several elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How to use "after" for several elements?

Initial position:

```
<div id="parent_div">
<div id="smth">data0</div>
<div id="this_to_move">data1</div>
<div id="this_to_move">data2</div>
<div id="this_to_move">data3</div>
<div id="smth">data4</div>
<div id="this_element_to_use">data5</div>
<div id="smth">data6</div>
</div>
```

The resultant:

```
<div id="parent_div">
<div id="smth">data0</div>
<div id="smth">data4</div>
<div id="this_element_to_use">data5</div>
<div id="this_to_move">data1</div>
<div id="this_to_move">data2</div>
<div id="this_to_move">data3</div>
<div id="smth">data6</div>
</div>
```

What is the most elegant way to do it using jQuery?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to switch to classes instead of ids as you won't be able to do something this way otherwise (ids should be unique to an element):

```
$('.this_to_move').insertAfter('.this_element_to_use');
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/sLonnLqz/